# Installing .NET frameworks and MSBuild on windows container

Tags: windows, docker, msbuild, dockerfile

I'm struggling to install software tools (MSBuild, .NET frameworks, Wix, etc) onto a windows docker container.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2016
SHELL ["powershell"]  

# Install Chocolatey  
RUN Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass  
RUN iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))  

# Install dotnet 4.6.2  
RUN choco install netfx-4.6.2-devpack -y  

# Install MSBuild 15.0  
RUN choco install microsoft-build-tools -y  

CMD ["powershell"]
```

When building the docker image, the install hangs with the message "Installing dotnetfx"... Has anyone successfully installed the .NET frameworks and MSBuild on a Windows container? I would really appreciate any advice. I am out of ideas.

Comment: Try installing the commands separately from terminal ... If these are hung up, it is the command's problem ... Try to differentiate between a shely script and a docker image...

Comment: What do you mean? The choco install commands runs just fine locally. The commands hang when running in docker

Comment: What exactly is the message the instalations?

Comment: How long have you waited? I remember that I got stuck at that stage, too, I do not remember if he passed through.

Comment: Like 30 minutes and it was still stuck. It simply just says "installing dotnetfx". I can't seem to get chocolatey to install any .NET frameworks from a Dockerfile. Using this base image https://github.com/compulim/docker-msbuild comes with most of the packages I need! I just need to figure out how to get chocolatey to work.

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/jagbal/2017/08/18/unable-to-install-net-framework-4-x-on-windows-server-core-os/